# empty-cells valid in CSS3?

Tags: css

Is the CSS2 property empty-cells valid in CSS3?

For those who don't know what empty-cells is: empty-cells removes the background and border of a cell when it is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS does not have versions. CSS 3 is *level 3* not version 3. Now see the [description of levels](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/#css-levels):

> Cascading Style Sheets does not have versions in the traditional sense; instead it has levels. Each level of CSS builds on the previous, refining definitions and adding features. The feature set of each higher level is a superset of any lower level.

Since it is valid at Level 2, it is also valid at Level 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is this link http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-tables/#empty-cells

> In the separated borders model, this property controls the rendering of borders and backgrounds around cells that have no visible content. Empty cells and cells with the ‘visibility’ property set to ‘hidden’ are considered to have no visible content. Cells are empty unless they contain one or more of the following:
>
> floating content (including empty elements),
>      in-flow content (including empty elements) other than whitespace that has been collapsed away by the ‘white-space’ property handling.

When this property has the value ‘show’, borders and backgrounds are drawn around/behind empty cells (like normal cells).

A value of `hide` means that no borders or backgrounds are drawn around/behind empty cells (see point 6 in “Table layers and transparency”). Furthermore, if all the cells in a row have a value of `hide` and have no visible content, the entire row behaves as if it had `display: none`.